# Oracle Apex Office Print: cannot generate excel report when source query returns null value

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a query very similar to this test query:

```
select
'file1' as "filename",
cursor (
    select
        cursor (
            select
                cursor (
                    select
                        'Test Customer' as CUSTOMER,
                        'Test Country' as COUNTRY,
                        'Test Port' as PORT
                    from
                        dual
                    where
                        1 = 2
                ) as "table_without_rows",
                cursor (
                    select
                        'Test Customer' as CUSTOMER,
                        'Test Country' as COUNTRY,
                        'Test Port' as PORT
                    from
                        dual
                    where
                        1 = 1
                ) as "table_with_rows"
            from
                DUAL
        ) as "list"
    from
        DUAL
    ) as "data"
from
    DUAL
```

Using AOP PLSQL api I am able to generating a report but with no data in it. If all the cursors return rows it works correctly. As its not throwing any errors I am not sure what is causing this behavior.

The template structure for excel file is given below:

```
{#list}{#table_without_rows}..(Column names)..{/table_without_rows}
... Some text and styles ...
{#table_with_rows}..(Column names)..{/table_with_rows}{/list}
```

*(edited)*
Apex Version: 5.1.3.00.05
AOP Version: 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which version of AOP are you using? does the error occur if you set the AOP url to apexofficeprint.com/api?

if you set the debugging to local from the AOP components settings, you should receive a JSON, if you send it to support@apexofficeprint.com we would gladly help you out with this issue.

EDIT: Bug on version 3.0, issue was fixed from version 3.1.

Comment: Hi @standan , I have edited my question and added the version numbers. Regarding AOP url, I believe I am using an On-Premise server as the url is different.

Comment: @HipHapLion, i just tested it locally and it seems to be a bug in AOP 3.0 which was fixed on AOP 3.1 versions and above. AOP's current version is 18.1.1 (the version was bumped from 3.5 -> 18.1 but is backwards compatible). Updating AOP should resolve this issue.